# Visual Studio Express 2010 Reporting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report

I hope someone can help; I would like to implement reporting in a project I am writing in Visual Studio Express Web Edition 2010 (MVC2 SQL Server Express backend). After Googling I came across this Microsoft site:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/Vsexpressvcs/thread/60c328ec-e34c-4937-be3b-e6fc41d35711

The link above describes that Reporting is supported in Visual Studio Express Web Edition via the ReportViewer 2010 redistributable (reports are written via Business Intelligence Studio [there is an add on for SQL Express]) and the control is added to the toolbox. 
I have installed the redistributable but cannot find the control to add to my toolbox – all I seem to have is the Crystal Reports viewer?

What am I doing wrong? What is the name of the control? Where does it get installed to? Or have I misunderstood, if so what are my options for getting some very simple reports published to the web (fixed layout forms)?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx

Comment: Prix, thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, this does not resolve the issue as you cannot bind to the report in Visual STudio Express. I have found a solution and will post shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have been struggling with the same situation described above and fall into one of the following categories small business (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2009/11/12/way-to-get-visual-studio-professional-for-free.aspx
 
Basically if you are trying to start your own company register for WebSiteSpark – very quick and easy all you need is a Microsoft passport and then you get access to MSDN editions of Visual Studio Professional and a few OS's.

If you are already a small business and need Microsoft development tools you can get MSDN editions by registering for BizSpark and receive three licence free years.
And finally if you are student register for the DreamSpark.

I hope this helps you all, I wont get into how bizarre it is that Microsoft has removed features but it is nice to know there is (in my opinion) a very awesome solution!

Cheers

David